# Change color of a part of string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text, matlab-guide

Suppose that we have these codes :

```
String_1 = 'hi';
String_2 = 'You';
set(handles.text,'String',[String_1',Who are ' String_2 '?']); %% handles.text refers to a static text in GUI
```

`String_2` should be `red` in sentence and other words should be default (`black`). I know that I can create a separate static text for `String_2` and change the color of it manually but Is anyway to change the color of `String_2` in above structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Try TeX formatting. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/108879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To color part of the string, you cprintf function.

You can reference to this: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a need for this, and here's a quick example combining the tex formatting noted above with sprintf in a one-liner:

```
cstr = strrep(sprintf('foo (bar) = %d',41),'bar','{\color{red}bar}');
```

Use `regexprep` for more versatile substitution